# What's the right way to seed a date field in phoenix framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, seeding

I am creating a phoenix api app. Here's my code.

```
alias CardsWeb.Repo
alias CardsWeb.Infrastructure.User

Repo.insert! %User{login: "user", firstname: "User", lastname: "User", dateOfBirth: "1999-5-18"}
```

I get the following error when I run it

```
** (CompileError) priv/repo/seeds.exs:15: Infrastructure.User.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct Infrastructure.User
```

Here's the entity definition.

```
defmodule Infrastructure.User do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "users" do
    field :dateOfBirth, :date
    field :firstName, :string
    field :lastName, :string
    field :login, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:login, :firstName, :lastName, :dateOfBirth])
    |> validate_required([:login, :firstName, :lastName, :dateOfBirth])
  end
end
```

**Update:** I noticed that firstname and lastname should be firstName and lastName. I corrected that, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add date as string directly, instead of adding it as string use `~D` sigil:

```
dateOfBirth: ~D[1999-05-18]
```

edit:
The namespace you aliased in your `seeds.exs` for user schema is also incorrect, change:

```
alias CardsWeb.Infrastructure.User
```

to

```
alias Infrastructure.User
```

Comment: It's still giving me the same error. Maybe the entire statement for initialization is wrong, and it has nothing to do with date parsing.

Comment: I noticed that firstname and lastname should be firstName and lastName. I corrected that, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Also, does the order of the variables matter?

Comment: `alias CardsWeb.Infrastructure.User` in seeds.exs is incorrect also, change it to `alias Infrastructure.User`

Comment: That was it! Thanks!